# Vuejs - Use Router push to go to a path two levels up

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a button, which on clicking performs a router push operation.

However, I wanted to navigate to path which is two levels up relative to current level and could not find any examples on how we achieve it.

Example: User is currently on page.com/app/users/id.
On clicking a button, user needs to be navigated to page.com/app/hello.

I tried using the below codes -
`router.push('../../hello')` as well as `router.push('/hello')`

But still it seems to be getting routed to `page.com/app/users/id/hello`

Any thoughts on what is the best way to navigate to the desired path using router push?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is any feature in Vue router to go level up or down like a directory traversal in Linux :) I see two ways of achieving what you need.

1. Using regex:

```js
const route = useRoute()
const router = useRouter()
const currentRoute = route.path
const toRoute = currentRoute.replace(/[a-z]+\/[a-z]+$/, 'hello')
router.push(toRoute)
```

2. dynamic + named route:

```js
// routes
const routes = [
  // dynamic segments start with a colon
  { path: '/app/:key', name: 'App'  },
]
```

```js
// inside setup script
const router = use Router()
router.push({name: 'App', params: { key: 'hello' }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response ! I feel the first approach seems to more suit my use-case. 
Is there a way to make the regex more dynamic as to replacing for any path after `/`.  For ex - Suppose if current path was `page.com/app/users` or if the current path was `page.com/users` - can we have a common regex to move to `page.com/hello` irrespective.

Comment: I was thinking something like -

`router.push(currentRoute.replace(/\/*/, "/hello"))` 

Will this work to replace any path after the `page.com/*` to `page.com/hello` ?

Comment: If page.com is the domain of your web, then why not just use `router.push('/hello')`. No over-engineering will be necessary. this is route page to `page.com/hello` irrespective of the current route.

Comment: I tried using that. If my current route was page.com/app/users. 
router.push('/hello') was default pushing it to page.com/app/users/hello.
Will give it a retry to see if i was missing anything

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to debug and see that the current URL should be `page.com/app/users/id`. To check this, you can console log before `router.push`.

`console.log(this.$route)` <-- This should log `page.com/app/users/id`

Now, You can try using the `resolve` function which will generate an absolute path from a relative path.

```
import { resolve } from 'vue-router';

this.$router.push(resolve('../../hello', this.$route))
```

> ---------- OR (Recommend way / Best Practice) ------------

Instead of navigating through relative path, You can achieve this by using the named Routes.

For ex **:**

In routing file **:**

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/app/hello', name: 'hello' },
  ...
  ...
  ...
];
```

In component script **:**

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'hello' });
```